# How do I define an array value from a integer?

Tags: php, arrays

Okay below I have attached my code, I'm trying to use the `$current_statement` and `$next_statement` to define the values in the array. the `$current_statement` is = to 7 and the `$next_statement` is  = to 8. What I'm trying to do is define the 7th and 8th value in the array from the using the two values from `$current_statement` and `$next_statement`.

```
   <?
       $date = array('16-01-14','16-01-28','16-02-14','16-02-28','16-03-14','16-03-28',
       '16-04-14','16-04-28','16-05-14','16-05-28','16-06-14','16-06-28','16-07-14',
       '16-07-28','16-08-14','16-08-28','16-09-14','16-09-28','16-10-14','16-10-28',
       '16-11-14','16-11-28','16-12-14','16-12-28');    


        $currentdate = date('y-m-d');


        foreach ($date as $i => $d) {
        if ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($date)-1 || $currentdate < $date[$i+1])) {
            $current_statement = $i;
            $next_statement = $i+1;
        } 

        }

    ?>
```

**Example**

I'm trying to use the two numeric values from the `$current_statement` and the `$next_statement` to select the value from the array. So for example if the `$current_statement` was = to 7 it would select the 7th value from the array and define it as a separate variable. And if the `$next_statement` was = to 8 it would select the 8th value from the array and define it as a separate variable. So I could easily echo out both variables.

Comment: Show us an example of the output you want to see

Comment: *...echo out two new variables which would use both the $current_statement and the $next_statement integers to select from the array the 7th and 8th value...*, are you trying to do this `$var1 = $date[$i];` and `$var2 = $date[$i+1];`?

Comment: What im trying to do is use the numeric value from the `$current_statement` and the numeric value from `$next_statement` to define the two values from the array.

Comment: @LewisDay Can you at least tell us what you meant by *...define the two values from the array*?

Comment: It is possible you will have an error here: $currentdate < $date[$i+1] or here: $var2 = $date[$i+1]; (if you are trying to do what @RajdeepPaul says) The error will be array index out of bound... if the iteration arrives to the last element of $date

Comment: read it thrice, no idea what your asking

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I've provided an example where I've tried to provide a better explanation. I was thinking that `$var1 = $date[$i];` and `$var2 = $date[$i+1];` which you suggested would work but it doesn't?

Comment: so um `$new1= $date[$current_statement]` and `$new2= $date[$next_statement]` ?

Comment: @Dagon Thankyou. was exactly what I was trying to achieve. Really appreciate it.

Comment: you sure where headed down a rabbit hole on that one :-)

Comment: hahahaah yeah I really appreciate it, I could have worded it a bit better :3 would'a helped xD

Comment: @LewisDay From seeing the *accepted* answer it seems like it does work, isn't it? :-)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Yess :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not totally clear on your requirement, so this answer is a bit of a guess, which of course I should not really do. But do you mean something like this

```
<?php
    $date = array('16-01-14','16-01-28','16-02-14','16-02-28','16-03-14',
                  '16-03-28','16-04-14','16-04-28','16-05-14','16-05-28',
                  '16-06-14','16-06-28','16-07-14', '16-07-28','16-08-14',
                  '16-08-28','16-09-14','16-09-28','16-10-14','16-10-28',
                  '16-11-14','16-11-28','16-12-14','16-12-28');    

    $currentdate = date('y-m-d');

    foreach ($date as $i => $d) {
        if ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($date)-1 || $currentdate < $date[$i+1])) {
            echo 'Current statement date = ' . $date[$i];
            echo 'Next statement date = ' . $date[$i+1];
        } 
    }
?>
```

In which case you do not need the 2 variables you created, you can just use `$i` and `$i+1`

Comment: @dagon Good job i didnt just dump code but `you did waned.` me. You might like to check your profile

Comment: @Dagon If you post a answer I'd accept yours It was just I wanted to mark it as solved aha. Both this answer and the answer you provided in the comments was correct.

Comment: no its all good @RiggsFolly im just confusing myself with the date

Comment: ummm but... am I or there is the possibility to go away from the bounds of the $date array???

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to prevent the index out of bound exception:

```
$current_statement  = false;
$next_statement     = false;
foreach ($date as $i => $d) 
{
    if ($id<count($date)-1 && ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($date)-1 || $currentdate < $date[$i+1]))) 
    {
        $current_statement  = $i;
        $next_statement     = $i+1;
    } 
}
if($current_statement)
{
    $current_date   = $date[$current_statement];
    $next_date      = $date[$next_statement];
}
```

And shortly, if you don´t need the $current_statement and $next_statement variables more:

```
foreach ($date as $i => $d) 
{
    if ($id<count($date)-1 && ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($date)-1 || $currentdate < $date[$i+1]))) 
    {
        $current_date   = $date[$i];
        $next_date      = $date[$i + 1];
    } 
}
```

**Forget this answer**
You are preventing with this clausure: $i == count($date)-1